# state data still keeps the previous state even after setState

Tags: reactjs, react-state

when I fetch data from my api successfully, I can display it using console.log, but somehow after I use a setState, the state still keeps the previous data. so when the page loads, the `console.log(data)` has an array of object containing data from the api, but `console.log(rute)` after the `setRute` still returns empty array. why is that?

this is my code

```
const MasterRute = () => {
  const [rute, setRute] = useState([]);

  const getRute = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/rute');
    const data = await response.json();
    // console.log(data); // [{id:"1", name:"AAA"}, {id: "2", name: "BBB"}]
    setRute(data);
    // console.log(rute); // [] ===> why is this empty?
  }
}
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useState` is asynchronous, so you won't see changes after `setRute`. You need to wait for the component re-rendered completely

```
const MasterRute = () => {
  const [rute, setRute] = useState([]);

  const getRute = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/rute');
    const data = await response.json();
    // console.log(data); // [{id:"1", name:"AAA"}, {id: "2", name: "BBB"}]
    setRute(data);
    
  }
  
  console.log(rute); //data updated on rendering
}
```

You can check [this article](https://dev.to/shareef/react-usestate-hook-is-asynchronous-1hia) for a better understanding

If you still really want to see data after `setRute`. You can get the result within [`setTimeout`](https://medium.com/@Rahulx1/understanding-event-loop-call-stack-event-job-queue-in-javascript-63dcd2c71ecd)

```
const MasterRute = () => {
  const [rute, setRute] = useState([]);

  const getRute = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/rute');
    const data = await response.json();
    // console.log(data); // [{id:"1", name:"AAA"}, {id: "2", name: "BBB"}]
    setRute(data);
    setTimeout(() => {
       console.log(rute); //data updated
    })
  }
  
}
```

Comment: not sure if setTimeout is a good way to guarantee having updated state, won't this create a rece condition?